# How to close a popup when a button is pressed?

Tags: php, html, email

I want to close a page when a button is pressed. I'm using the script `add_address.php` to output a list of email addresses from the `message` box and I want to output the email addresses to the `text` box in the `send.php` script

Here is the code for add_address.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Add Email Addresses...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="send.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea></td>

        </tr>

        <td colspan="2" align="left">
           <input type="submit" name="send" value="Add Email" style="height:35px; width:100px">
        </td>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Here is the code for send.php:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['message'])) 
    {
        $emails = explode("\n", $_POST['message']); // explode textarea on a line break into an array
        $email_str = implode(", ", $emails); // take each of the emails and implode together with the ,
     }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Send Email</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"  />
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="pr_send.php" method="POST">
    <table> 
        <!-- <tr>
            <td>From:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="from"></td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" name="to" value="" style="height:24px; width:24px; background:url('addressbook.png'); border:none;" onClick="Popup()"> To:</td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="to" value="<?php if (!empty($email_str)) { echo $email_str; } ?>" style="height:15px; width:650px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subject" style="height:15px; width:650px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message:</td>
            <td><textarea name="message" cols="90" rows="20"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
               <input type="submit" name="send" value="" style="height:35px; width:100px; background:url('send.png'); border:none">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Popup() 
{
  window.open("add_address.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=500, width=400, height=400");
}
</script>

</html>
```

What my snippets have show, it will only allowed me to output the list of email addresses in the `message` box and it will redirect to the `send.php` page to output the list of email addresses in the `text` box without close it.

Comment: You have a button in add_address.pph which closes that.  You have a button in send.php which closes that.  What doesn't get closed?

Comment: @dcromley a button in add_address.php didn't get close when i press it. can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't using window.open, instead you should use another way like creating popup function with Jquery and CSS or use library that already created (tagit.js):

http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

Comment: What? I'm using a window.open to creating the popup. You got a bad answer there and i hope someone will give you a down vote for giving me the bad answer.

Comment: Use it http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/ for popup, what i mean tagit for tag email in your form..

Answer (score 0):

I may be off base, but I think you want a javascript-only dialog to get your email addresses.  You might search that.  I came up with this model (a start for me):
EDIT: model extended to answer comment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><!-- HTML5 -->
<!-- - - - - head - - - - --><head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>..</title>
<!-- - - - - script - - - - --><script type="text/javascript">
function opendialog() {
  var elt1 = document.getElementById("dialogid");
  elt1.style.display = "inline";
  }
function closedialog() { // process the dialog data
  var elt1 = document.getElementById("iddialog");
  var elt2 = document.getElementById("idbase");
  elt2.value = elt1.value;
  var elt3 = document.getElementById("dialogid");
  elt3.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
<!-- - - - - style - - - - --><style type="text/css">
td:nth-child(1) { width:100px; }
td:nth-child(2) { width:400px; }
table input     { width:100%; }
#dialogid { display: none; background: #fee;
            position: fixed; left: 200px; top: 100px; width: 800px; height: 50px; }
</style>
</head>
<!-- - - - - body - - - - --><body><div id="bodydiv">
<table><tr>
  <td></td><td><button type="button" onclick="opendialog();">Opendialog</button></td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>To:</td><td><input type="text" id="idbase" /></td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>Subject:</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>Message:</td><td><textarea cols="90" rows="20"></textarea></td>
</tr><tr>
  <td></td><td><button type="button">Sendmail</button></td>
</tr></table>
<div id="dialogid">
  This is the dialog<br />
  To: <input type="text" id="iddialog" />
  <button type="button" onclick="closedialog();">Closedialog</button>
</div>
</div></body></html><!-- - - - - end of it all - - - - -->
```

Comment: where do i need to put that code in which script? add_address.php or send.php?

Comment: @Tim Cullen - I'm suggesting that you not use php to add address -- that you do that in javascript.  I've extended my model a bit.  You'll have to do your exploding, etc. in javascript.  There's only this one routine.  No submitting except the final "sendmail".